# need advice on mysql normalization and php class structure

Tags: php, mysql, database, class-design, normalization

i am trying to build a system that logs, media (photo, video, audio) upload statistic. so i come up with 3 tables, 1 for audio, 1 for video, and 1 for photo. and here's the structure

```
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| member_id | int(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| counter   | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| daydate   | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| epochtime | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

all three tables has the same fields, since i think (so far) i need to differentiate the medias on each and particular table, is this redundant ??

anyway since each of the media is treated the same, so i think i should only build once class and kinda use the methods depending of what media i am accessing at the time. here's the class :

```
require_once(INC_PATH.DS.'database.php');

    class Log extends DatabaseObject {

        protected static $db_fields = array('id', 'member_id', 'counter',  'daydate', 'epochtime');

        public $id;
        public $member_id;
        public $counter;
        public $daydate;
        public $epochtime;

        public function find_counter($table_name){
            global $database;
            $time = date('d-m-Y');
            $timestamp = time();

            $sql  = "SELECT * FROM ". $table_name;
            $sql .= " WHERE daydate = '".$this->daydate."'";            
            $sql .= " AND member_id = '".$this->member_id."'";

            return self::find_by_sql($sql);
        }

        public function add_log($table_name){
            global $database;
            $tes = $this->find_counter();

            if(!empty($tes)){
                $sql  = "UPDATE ".$table_name;
                $sql .= " SET counter = counter+1";
                $sql .= " WHERE daydate = '".$this->daydate."'";
                $sql .= " AND member_id = '".$this->member_id."'";

                $database->query($sql);
                return ($database->affected_rows() == 1) ? true : false;
            }else{

                $sql  = "INSERT INTO ".$table_name;
                $sql .= " (id, member_id, user_privelege, counter, daydate, epochtime)";
                $sql .= " VALUES ('', '".$this->member_id."'";
                $sql .= " , '".$this->user_privelege."', '1', '".$this->daydate."', '".$this->epochtime;
                $sql .= "')";

                $database->query($sql);
                return ($database->affected_rows() == 1) ? true : false;
            }
        }

  }
```

so far this is pretty much working but, i still have doubts on the way i break the table in to 3 tables, and the way i use the $table_name as parameter. any suggestions for better approach ?? i really want to improve my codes, thank you very much

Regards

**UPDATE**

alright, based on everybody's answer, i would like to clear somethings up:

1. i only need to log the uploaded media
2. i already have another separate table to record other information (length, filename, titles, etc) for each media.

lets just say i add a field called "media_id" and merge the table into one, and since the way that i add and update my rows is based on the day-date, it will INSERT if the given daydate and the member_id is not found, and otherwise it will UPDATE, i think i should also change the way my add_log() method works, into something like:

```
public function add_log($table_name, $media_id){
    global $database;
    $tes = $this->find_counter();

    if(!empty($tes)){
        $sql  = "UPDATE ".$table_name;
        $sql .= " SET counter = counter+1";
        $sql .= " WHERE daydate = '".$this->daydate."'";
        $sql .= " AND member_id = '".$this->member_id."'";
        $sql .= " AND media_id = '".$media_id."'";

        $database->query($sql);
        return ($database->affected_rows() == 1) ? true : false;
    }else{

        $sql  = "INSERT INTO ".$table_name;
        $sql .= " (id, member_id, media_id, counter, daydate, epochtime)";
        $sql .= " VALUES ('', '".$this->member_id."'";
        $sql .= " , '".$media_id."', '1', '".$this->daydate."', '".$this->epochtime;
        $sql .= "')";

        $database->query($sql);
        return ($database->affected_rows() == 1) ? true : false;
    }
}
```

what do you guys think ??

thanks again

Comment: For the 'edit', based on the requirements you've stated (that this is just logging uploads), what you've shown above seems mostly good.  One thing to think about is how you'll determine the media_id - do you store the 1,2,3 as photo, audio, etc. in the application code somewhere, or do you retrieve them from the media_type table at some point and use them later (I'm thinking about what happens if you add  another media type later, etc)

Comment: @Kris i'll store the media_id information inside another table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it all in one table and have a media_type column.

```
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| member_id | int(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| counter   | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| daydate   | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| epochtime | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| media_type| int     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Create a foreign key relationship to another table that defines media_type.

```
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| media_type_id| int  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| description  | text | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 +-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

This would hold media_type_id (e.g. 1) and media_type_description (e.g. audio).
e.g.

```
1, audio
2, video
3, photo
```

The main table would then just include on each row the id of 1, 2, 3 to denote which media type it is.  You can then use this from your application to constrain via the WHERE clause, which media you're referring to.  e.g. SELECT * FROM maintable WHERE media_type_id = 3 to just get the photos.

Comment: Having a type column to differentiate is not a good way of design. May be creating seperate classes for each table is good

Comment: Why not?  It's a regularly used feature of 3NF.  The alternative is creating many tables with the same column structure for each different 'type'.

Comment: So if sometime later he wants to store some media specific info like video's length or something how will you capture that? Putting NULL for all other type of logs? Thats bad

Comment: This depends on the OPs wider requirements, which aren't clear from the question.  It comes down to an object relational impedance mismatch (http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html).   And the answer is always 'it depends'.  OP may just need to track upload stats and not care about data specific to each type.  In which case proposal above is fine.  If there is a change case that each media type will have very different data stored then yes separate tables would be better.  But there is no evidence of that in the original question.  Hence my recommendation

Comment: Ya i accept it. Unless he has a very rigid requirements i dont want to suggest that

Comment: thank you very much for the discussion guys, i updated my question. what do you think ??

Answer (score 2):

Make it one table with an extra column "media_type". Your design would require you to make an extra table for every new media type and that is *possibly* poor design.

Comment: I dont think thats a poor design. Having a single table for different domain concepts is a poor design. Some time later if he wishes to store the length of the video. Where does it fit in?

Comment: Audio has length too, so again there is commonality - maybe it would need to be a nullable column because of the photos however.  So may well make sense to keep it in the same table.  However we don't know what his change cases are at this point and it appears there is enough commonality in his data structures to recommend merging them like this.

Comment: But they are really different domain concepts. Mixing different kinds of entity just because they have same cardinality is really bad

Comment: For this example, I would probably fit it in the same table, even if it isn't applicable to photos. What if he wanted to add a title for every media type?

Comment: I would still keep them seperate. That design atleast gives you a room for extending it.

Comment: Do you also prefer to store men and women in different tables because men don't have a bra size?

Comment: ref - "they are different types of entity".  Potentially they aren't.  They could well all just types of media, and that media is a granular enough level to store this at.  In the same way an HR system might track people in an 'employees' table when really they're very different, as some are managers, so are executives, etc.  It depends on the wider data domain model which we can't comment on as we don't know it.  As a designer OP has to make that judgement call.

Comment: And to conclude, I just added "possibly" to my original answer which adds the necessary nuance.